# 1 Dimensional Linear Induction Motor Model Derivation Assistance

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, electric-fields, electrical-engineering

I'm reading through "Theories of the Linear, Induction Motor and Compensated Linear Induction Motor" Yamamura (1973) and was wondering if anyone can explain:

1. Which law this "rot. H" law is that the paper refers to that the author uses to find the relationship between magnetic flux density and the currents in the primary and secondary for equation (1).

I thought it was either Ampere's or Biot-Savart's but the inclusion of the coefficients of the air gap length and permeability of air and not free-space is throwing me off. Maybe it is some motor specific version of those two laws I am unfamiliar with? I'm assume the original law referenced is in terms of "H" and the permeability of air comes from B=uH.

Thank you!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is from Ampere's Circuit Law. I found a paper that cites this one that did a much better job of going through where (1) is from , the permeability used in either case should be the typical uo vacuum permeability, the u of air is 1.00000037 so theyre pretty much interchangeable in this case from what I understand. I also misunderstood this as looking for the magnetic field in the secondaries or primary where this is calculating the magnetic field in the AIR GAP hence the gap length being incorporated. [image: Electromagnetic Force Analysis in Linear Induction Motors, Considering End Effect Shiri 2016]